# ul List elements will have bizarre justification even though there is nothing to modify it

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So no one else is having this problem in the course I'm taking.

As you can see I'm using

Chrome 74.0.3729.169 Desktop Windows
Firefox 67.0.1 Desktop Windows

html:

```
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>





  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">DrinDrin</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToCollapse" aria-controls="navbarToCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>



    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToCollapse">

      <!-- ml-auto tells ul to move over,make space for left element -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Projects</anchor>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Foods</anchor>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Link</anchor>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>




  <!-- <button class="btn btn-dark">THBUTTON</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">THBUTTON</button>
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-outline-dark">THBUTTON</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">THBUTTON</button> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing tags need to match your opening tags. So

```
<a href="">Words Here</anchor> needs to be <a href="">Words Here</a>.
```

On an unrelated note, jQuery version isn't loading. Try https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js instead of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @user:11589910 Bless you for answering... oh thats terrible. I looked for SO LONG